# Create World matrix for augmented reality application in windows 8 tablet

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-runtime

Can anyone please suggest how to create 'World Matrix' for augmented reality application in a Windows 8 tablet.  The following code already exists for windows phone:

```
Matrix world = Matrix.CreateWorld(Vector3, Vector3,  Vector3);
```

where `CreateWorld` is from `Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Matrix` which is not supported in Windows 8 Tablet unlike Windows Phone.

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm fairly certain XNA was depricated prior to Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started.

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
Vector3 forward = new Vector3(1,0,0);
Vector3 up = new Vector3(0,1,0);
Matrix world = Matrix.CreateWorld(position, forward, up);
```

Comment: The above code is not compatible with Windows 8 as XNA framework is not supported. Please provide an alternative approach to create World Matrix.